# how to : spark yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have set up a hadoop cluster with 3 machines one master and 2 slave
In the master i have installed spark

```
SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.4.0 SPARK_YARN=true sbt/sbt clean assembly
```

Added HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop spark-env.sh

```
 Then i ran SPARK_JAR=./assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.4.0.jar HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 1 examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

I checked localhost:8088 and i saw application SparkPi running..

Is it just this or i should install spark in the 2 slave machines..
How can i get all the machine started?

Is there any help doc out there.. I feel like i am missing something..

In spark standalone more we start the master and worker
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://IP:PORT

i also wanted to know how to get more than one worked running in this case as well

and i know we can can configure slaves in conf/slave but can anyone share an example

Please help i am stuck

Comment: I found localhost inside conf/slave,  i added localhost thrice and i can see 3 workers running is this the right way to get more workers to run or is there any other way.. Also If we give ip of the other machine will it server as worker? share some example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Spark 1.1.0, as it says in the documentation (http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/submitting-applications.html#master-urls), for the *master* parameter you can use values *yarn-cluster* or *yarn-client*. You do not need to use *deploy-mode* parameter in that case.

You do not have to install Spark on all the YARN nodes. That is what YARN is for: to distribute your application (in this case Spark) over a Hadoop cluster.